# Java Servlet SOAP request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, soap, soap-client

I dusted Java off recently so maybe there are a lot of stupids errors in my code. My objective is to make a servlet which sends a SOAP request to a server. I used [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqgc/index.html) for creating a SOAP client. I added it to my servlet class. It obviosly doesn't work. Can you give me tips for improve this servlet and to understand the servlet's logic?

Here's is the relevant snippet:

```
public class SOAPRequest extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public SOAPRequest() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SOAPConnectionFactory myFct = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection myCon = myFct.createConnection();
        MessageFactory msgFct = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage msg = msgFct.createMessage();
        SOAPPart mySPart = msg.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope myEnvp = mySPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = myEnvp.getBody();

        Name bodyName = envelope.createName("GetLastTradePrice", "m", "http://eztrade.com");
        SOAPBodyElement gltp = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
        Name myContent = envelope.createName("symbol");
        SOAPElement mySymbol = gltp.addChildElement(myContent);
        mySymbol.addTextNode("SUNW");

        message.saveChanges();

        URLEndpoint endPt = new URLEndpoint("http://eztrade.com//quotes");

        SOAPMessage reply = myCon.call(message, endPt);
        myCon.close();
    }
```

Comment: What do yo mean by "not working"?

Comment: I get error 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problems:
envelope cannot be resolved
envelope cannot be resolved
message cannot be resolved
URLEndpoint cannot be resolved to a type
URLEndpoint cannot be resolved to a type
message cannot be resolved to a variable
SOAPRequest.doGet(SOAPRequest.java:44)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required jar file in classpath? The code suggest you are using SAAJ. Please get the latest jar files and it should work.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis-saaj -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have imported javax.xml.soap, if i didn't get the SAAJ i cannot import it, am i right?

Comment: Yes you can . Also check this linkvhttps://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/soapsaajxml-issues-when-migrating-to-java-6-with-axis-1-2/

Comment: So i have just to download this saaj.jar and import into my project?